# how to use ExecutorService in webapp

Tags: java, executorservice

I have a restful webapp. request can contain large set of data. so inside the restful webservice logic, I want to split the processing into 2 parts. the 1st part will receive data, validate data and save data to database. the 2nd part is really going through the data and apply business logic to it. The 2nd part can take a while to finish.

so I'm thinking to make 2nd part as Runnable, and to use ExecutorService, like

```
`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`
```

so I think I can have a singleton to hold this ExecutorService instance, when the 1st part finish, it can submit the job to the ExecutorService, and ExecutorService will execute the 2nd part.
This way the ExecutorService will holds a thread pool, the thread can also be reused. So basically I use ExecutorService for background processing

But I'm not sure about a few questions:

1. is this the right way to use ExecutorService? Is there any better way to do it?

   Since I'm already inside a webapp server (I'm using Wildfly), can I also use ExecutorService like this? Somehow I feel ExecutorService is usually used either on server side or in a standalone application.
2. how and when do I initial the shutdown for the ExecutorService?

   Since I'm making it as Singleton, I expect this ExecutorService instance keeps running until the application is undeployed or the server is shutdown. So when and how the shutdownNow() can be triggered?
   also when the server is shutdown, even the tasks inside ExecutorService is not done, I guess I have no control on it. Is there anything I can do to at least log something?

Thanks,
Helen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to use it that way.
You should be able (not sure about wildfly) to control startup and shutdown by registering context listener in your web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.stackOv.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and implement it like this

```
class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
            // start
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
            // shutdown
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the caller of the API consume the output of Step 2 (business logic processing) synchronously ? If not I would suggest not to do the 2nd step  as part of the REST API.

You can expose an API to do only the step 1 (validate and save to DB). For Step 2, you can have a daemon that wakes up at periodic interval and checks if there is any new data to be processed since the last processed time. There are multiple ways to implement this scheduled task, one example is [Spring Scheduled Task](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

This way you get division of labour and asynchronous processing.

Comment: The API does not need to consume the output of Step 2. it is my understanding that if I have a ExecutorService instance running, and each step2 is submitted to ExecutorService, then step 1 can return response to caller right after submitting job to ExecutorService without waiting for Step2.  But you are saying I should just have another daemon to process the data, so the API doesn't even worry about step 2. right?

Comment: Yes exactly. API should not worry about Step2

Comment: I got it. I think I'll need a scheduler for checking records which failed the processing. And step2 maybe can just be part of that.